# Why is my .dae file not applying materials correctly in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, 3d, scenekit

I worked with a freelancer to create a few 3D models and I'm now trying to apply materials to them in Xcode, but some of the models are behaving weirdly. When I import the .dae file, instead of the default gray color models usually have, they are part green, part black, and part transparent. When I try to apply a material, the material only applies to the green parts, and any color seems to blend with the green.

The freelancer is at a loss because he says there shouldn't be anything different about the models that are working and the ones that aren't.

I've attached a screenshot of one of the broken models and one of the working ones, both with the same material applied.

Any help would be much appreciated!

[image: Broken Model]
[image: Working Model]

I tried playing around with different material settings and searching for materials that were secretly applied to broken model, but to no avail.

Comment: This might be related to a texture coordinate problem within the model, or a wrapping issue. When you expand the different materials (on the right panel), you should see a section wrap. Try set it to repeat. If this does not resolve your problem, you can provide me your model, and I will check it.

Comment: @ZAY Thanks for the response. I can't seem to find section wrap in the materials panel, unfortunately. Here is a folder with one of the broken models and one of the working ones [3D Models](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/11FBiHqYCkcZTOIZfGDHyyMcWB_PJ4NOF?usp=sharing). Any insight you have would be much appreciated!

Comment: okay, give me some time to check over. and could you provide me the diffuse texture, if you have?

Comment: Okay, awesome! I've just been using flat colors from the diffusion dropdown in Xcode, rather than using images. I did try using images but it didn't fix the issue.

Comment: @ZAY I just figured this out!There was a Colors item under Geometry Sources that I had to remove (in the Attributes Inspector on the right panel). Still don't understand exactly what that is, but it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this issue by removing a Colors item that was in Geometry Sources. I'm still not sure exactly what it is (I'm a SceneKit noob), but removing it did the trick.

[image: Screenshot of Xcode showing Geometry Sources (before removing Colors item)]

Comment: I can confirm, when you remove the color element the model get one single color everywhere/overall - I also had a look at the texture coordinates. Those are a little bit weird, but if you do NOT plan to use image textures as texture elements you will be good. Keep in mind your models are kind of high-poly, which will easily make troubles when using scenekit very intense. It depends how many models of such type you will add to your scene. It will very fast increase the memory and the GPU usage. Try to use low-poly models wherever you can, when building large scenes.

Comment: @ZAY Thanks for taking a look! We actually did reduce the poly count quite a bit since the version I sent you, but there will only be one model in the scene so hopefully won't be an issue regardless. I don't need to use image textures on these, but yeah, I might have to solve that mystery in the future...

Answer (score 1):

This answer is just to illustrate the issue you might have with the texture coordinates. If you use one single color and not textures, you'll be good. But if you plan to add some texturing, you might want to unwrap your model in a different way. the following images should illustrate that.

This model shows texture coordinates that looks like a perspective projection and you loose a lot of space. It cannot be textured in a good manner. it should be unwrapped differently (illustration from Blender).
[image: illustration from Blender]

This model here is perfectly unwrapped with non overlapping textures and alomst every free space on the image texture is used for anything (illustration from Blender).
[image: illustration from Blender]

hope I could help in some manner.

Comment: Thanks ZAY! I will refer to this in the future.